# Not able to edit Approved Emails in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, approval-process, email-studio

I have recently started working on SFMC and my org uses approval process for emails.

I was assigned to change the HTML email contents for active journeys, but those emails are not editable and say that the content has been approved and it cannot be edited.

Now, I think I am left with the only option of duplicating all the emails and injection the duplicate versions into the journeys.

Are there any better alternatives?
Is there any way of getting those emails out of the approval process or changing the approval stage and then editing the emails, then resubmitting?

Any answers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation:

- Approvals prevents unapproved emails from being sent or scheduled, and also prevent approved emails from being edited. To edit approved emails, first withdraw them.
- To withdraw the approval of a shared email in a business unit, first unshare the email. Unsharing the email deletes all copies from other business units.
- If you withdraw an approved email that has pending or scheduled jobs, the email remains pending or scheduled in its originally approved version, even if you edit it.
- To edit an approved email in an active journey, edit the email from the journey activity to ensure that the journey uses the edits. If you edit the email outside of the journey activity, refresh the activity to ensure that the journey uses the edits.

Link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_approvals_considerations.htm&type=5

How to withdraw an email?

> Open the email and click on the arrow next to 'Approved' and choose
>   'Withdraw'. Once the email is withdrawn the Edit functionality becomes
>   available. In order to use this content to Send, you will need to go
>   through the Approval process again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I cannot see any arrow next to 'Approved' on the emails. Is it because I was not assigned proper permissions. If yes, which permission in-particular I should ask.